# Maven can't find java path

Tags: java, maven

I have installed maven on my machine with Java already present. but when i hit any maven command it tells Java path is not set correctly. I tried with a lot of export commands as well but din't worked out for me

**Logs**

```
[root@sandbox test]# mvn --version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java/bin/java
[root@sandbox test]# whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/lib/java /etc/java /usr/share/java /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java
[root@sandbox test]# ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Sep 12  2017 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
[root@sandbox test]# ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Sep 12  2017 /etc/alternatives/java -> /opt/jdk1.8.0_141/bin/java
```

Anybody want more inputs on this can paste the command and i will paste the output for it.

Comment: can you please post what you get when run the command echo $JAVA_HOME

Comment: /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java

Comment: You need to export JAVA_HOME and add that to the end of PATH variable

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/582100 This should help you

Comment: It's only necessary to set JAVA_HOME correctly to get Maven working. Adding to the PATH is only needed if you like to call Java yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `JAVA_HOME` as `/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_131`